# Making an AJAX request to an MVC controller and getting the data from the response in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

On button click I am trying to send a product name value that the user enters into a textbox to the server to be modified and then back to the page using AJAX. I am getting into the ChangeName method in the controller but not getting into my success function to alert the new name.

**The JS:**

```
    $("#changeNameButton").click(function () {
        var productName = $("#Name").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Products/ChangeName/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {name: productName},
            success: successFunc
        });
    });


    function successFunc(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
```

**The controller:**

```
    public string ChangeName(string name)
    {
        string changedName = ChangeNameHelper(name);
        return changedName;
    }
```

If anyone can give recommendations on the proper way to make asynchronous calls to a controller in MVC5/6 this would be great.

My main problem is that I am never getting into the successFunc() on response.

Comment: You might wanna `return name;` rather than `return ChangeName(name)` as you're making recusive calls.

Comment: It looks like the `ChangeName` function just calls itself, which would result in an infinite loop. It never gets to success because the server would never return a response to the client.

Comment: @remdevtec I am now setting the new changed name to a variable then trying to return it, but the alert still isn't happening. Can you return just a string back to AJAX? Or do I have to return a JsonResult or ActionResult instead?

Comment: @BlakeRivell It looks like it's doing the same thing. By calling `ChangeName(name)` as the first line, you'll just keep calling the `ChangeName` function infinitely. You either need to call another function (to do some work) or just `return name;`

Comment: I apologize! in my actual code ChangeName is a helper function with a different name. Now look at my updated code.

Comment: Should the object you're posting be {name: productName} ? there isn't a variable there called 'name', which is what your code currently shows

Comment: When passing in I am using JSON to specify the name parameter in the controllers action. But as far as the response is concerned I want it to just be a string.

Comment: Yes - but it looks to me like the JSON doesn't specify a name parameter. It sets the JSON's property 'name' to a variable called 'name', and that variable doesn't look to exist. It looks like you meant to put productName.

Comment: My apologies its updated, another typo. I can promise you that I am getting into the controller action error free. It is getting the response in the success function that is my problem. I am never getting in there.

Comment: Try using browser debugging to view the actual response in the Network tab. If it's 500, view the results to see the error. I'm suspecting @Anthony is partially right (data should be `{name: productName}`. But there may be another issue we're not seeing in this example code.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Do you have some network traffic inspector like Fiddler? If so, do you get a 200 Code in response to your ajax call?

Comment: @remdevtec Yes, the response is 200OK. Still not able to alert the response in the browser though or ensure that its even getting into my success function.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Do you happen to have another `successFunc` identifier, variable/function in your code?

Comment: no, at this point I am just doing the following: success: function (data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); }

Comment: @BlakeRivell In your network traffic inspector, can you see the JSON structure as text or as raw bytes? with the appropriate values?

Comment: I will check, but I did notice it is returning a response of OK, but then throwing an error that says: SyntaxError: Unexpected token c. This leads me to believe my data isn't in correct format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101123/discussion-between-remdevtec-and-blake-rivell).

Comment: Everyone, I apologize! My problem was because I was setting dataType: 'JSON' when I should have been setting it to 'text' since a simple string is all I wanted to return from my controller. Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment, if you return just a string MVC will convert that to json.

Now, in your updated code you still call a method inside itself. Please call `string changedName = ChangeNameForResult(name);` or any function with another name.

Comment: I think my problem is that I am never getting into my success function. Not sure what could be going wrong. I see in the debugger in the controller that it returns the changed name string.

Answer (score 0):

Install Newtonsoft.Json via nuget package manager and in your controller do this

```
Public ActionResult ChangeName(string name)
{
     // get your object you want to serialize let's say res
     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);

}
```

Comment: I think you have me on the right track but I am not dealing with objects in this case. Just a simple string that I want to return. Can res be a string? Intellisense is saying no.

Comment: return Content(YourString, "application/json");

Comment: Still not able to alert the response. I am getting a 200OK in the network tab which is strange.

Comment: Did you change your action returning ActionResult instead of string ??

Comment: Yes, but still not getting into the success function to alert the data result. And by the way is that something that is required when using jQuery AJAX?

Comment: Try to add an error function to your ajax and log or alert the response and see what you get !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101122/discussion-between-lyz-and-blake-rivell).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set dataType: 'text' rather than JSON since I am returning a simple string.

dataType is the type of data being returned and contentType is the type of data being sent.